# Archivo Bash (Linux) Moverse a una carpeta en especifico

Tags: linux, bash

Soy algo nueva en programación en linux y tengo un pequeño programa de lotes que crea un folder con la fecha actual. EL cual se crea así:

```
DATE=$(date +"%d_%m_%y")
mkdir $DATE
```

Después crea un archivo y un backup del archivo. Estos dos deben de ir dentro del folder con la fecha creada. Mi código quedo asi:

```
cd /home/mint/Desktop/12_03_19
read -rsp "Presione enter para continuar"
nano texto.txt
cp texto.txt copia.txt
```

Mi pregunta es: existe alguna manera de crear ambos archivos en el folder con la fecha actual SIN que tenga que escribir el nombre especifico de él? Ya que tendría que estar editando el código cada día que usara el programa para cambiarle la fecha al

```
cd /home/mint/Desktop/12_03_19
```

Answer (score 3):

No tendrías que poner la fecha a mano, sólo utilizar la fecha que guardas en tu variable `DATE`

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +'%d_%m_%y')
RUTA=<escribe tu ruta>
NOMBRE_ARCHIVO=texto.txt

NUEVA_CARPETA=$RUTA/$DATE
ARCHIVO=$NUEVA_CARPETA/$NOMBRE_ARCHIVO

mkdir $NUEVA_CARPETA

nano $ARCHIVO
cp $ARCHIVO{,.bak}  #  Puedes usar esta forma para crear una copia del archivo
                    #+ con el sufijo ".bak" al nombre del archivo.
#  O puedes usar la forma usual de
#+ NOMBRE_RESPALDO=respaldo.txt
#+ ARCHIVO_RESPALDO=$NUEVA_CARPETA/$NOMBRE_RESPALDO
#+
#+ cp $ARCHIVO $ARCHIVO_RESPALDO
```

Y resultaría algo por el estilo.

```
$ ./reemplazar.sh
$ ls
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1 512 Mar 12 18:56 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1 512 Mar 12 18:53 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1 512 Mar 12 18:56 12_03_19
-rwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1 202 Mar 12 18:55 reemplazar.sh
$ ls 12_03_19
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1 512 Mar 12 18:56 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1 512 Mar 12 18:56 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1  10 Mar 12 18:56 texto.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 usuario1 usuario1  10 Mar 12 18:56 texto.txt.bak
$ head 12_03_19/*
==> 12_03_19/texto.txt <==
archivo1

==> 12_03_19/texto.txt.bak <==
archivo1
```

Comment: recomendaría no usar variables en todo mayúsculas, para no colisionar con las variables de entorno+

Comment: Alguna vez pensé eso, pero luego recordé que las suelo poner en español y todas las que conozco están en inglés. Entonces, mientras las ponga en español, no suelo preocuparme.

Comment: @Marco y si tienes un programa escrito por un programador que habla español y esta pensando exactamente lo mismo, metiendo variables en mayúsculas? Y si usas una palabra en español que es igual en ingles? Por ejemplo, `EDITOR` y `VISUAL` son variables que existen por defecto. Otras posiblemente problemáticas son cosas tipo `TERM`, `TERMINAL`, etc.

Comment: @terdon que afortunadamente no es el caso de esta pregunta. Y pues en ese caso hay varias cosas de las que me ayudaría y serían el poner las variables con guion bajo o doble guión bajo. Además que dudo mucho que en un script para copiar o cosas básicas, el cambiar variables de tipo `EDITOR` o `VISUAL` afecte en algo, muy diferente a `BASH`, etc.

Comment: @terdon Además, que para mi sería gracioso encontrar (que si lo he encontrado) que en lugar de `while [[ $i -gt 9 ]]` un `mientras [[ $1 -mq 9 ]]` o que en lugar de un `$BASH_ALIASES` un `$APODOS_BASH`.

Comment: https://github.com/primitivorm/latino

Comment: Jaja, buenismo el `mientras`! Y si, claro, no digo que es esencial. Solo que evitar las mayúsculas en el shell es una buena costumbre y me parece útil responder así ya que es algo que pueda confundir a la gente que no tengan mucha experiencia. Pero quizás es que estoy acostumbrado a [unix.se] donde somos muy tiquismiquis con este tipo de cosas.

Comment: @terdon Pues esa comunidad es principalmente angloparlante, es decir, las variables, palabras reservadas, están en el mismo idioma que se habla principalmente. `$RUTA` no es lo mismo que `$PATH` ya que hasta se siente que el segundo puede colisionar. Esa comunidad tiene que ser así por características del idioma dominante. En español, para palabras exclusivas del idioma, yo no le veo tanto problema. Pero concuerdo con @fedorqui y contigo respecto a la importancia del nombrar variables y más en algo tan anárquico como el shell scripting.

Comment: por qué no usar `touch` para la creación del archivo?

Comment: @julio Ya tiene tiempo esta pregunta, pero por lo que veo, quiere usar `nano` para crearlo y también para editarlo.